# Why does searching using ?? on a package name return seemingly unrelated packages

Tags: r, package

I created a package `terDA` with vignettes. I want to search for my package using `??` but when I type

> ??terDA

in the R console, it returns seemingly unrelated results

[image: i68.photobucket.com/albums/i5/clairsang/vignettes_zps72fe3780.png]

Why are there information from other packages appearing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `??terDA` is issuing a call to `` `?`(?terDA) ``. The `` `?` `` function takes two arguments

```
> args(`?`)
function (e1, e2) 
NULL
```

It is basically a convience operator for the `help.search` function. `help.search` takes a pattern argument which in your case after the `?` operator has worked its magic will be `terDA`. For patterns with character length 5 or greater help.search searches by fuzzy matching using `agrep`. For character lengths less then five `help.search` by default assumes the pattern is a regular expression and matches using grep. Hence in your case what is happening is you are being returned the fuzzy matches.

If you want to search only in your package space you can use `??terDA::terDA` . You can also search using fields. For example `name??terDA` would search for fuzzy search for `terDA` only in filenames.

If you want greater control over your help query you can look at the documentation for `?help.search` or `?help`

As an example here is `> ??apply`

[image: apply1]

here is `> name??apply` which does fuzzy matching on the filenames

[image: apply2]

and finally `> name??base::apply` which fuzzy searches for `apply` in the base package filenames:

[image: apply3]

Comment: YMMV with respect to RStudio as its conceivable they may intercept such calls.